# Running console application on windows application with button click

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, process, console-application

I am trying to run a Console Application from a Windows Application. This Windows Application acts as a user interface. So when you click on a specific button, the new process (myConsoleApp.exe) will start. My question is where should I put myConsoleApp.exe? I am using Visual Studio 2013. Should I put it in the same folder as my windows app? Or somewhere more specific for the following code to work properly.

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Process p = new Process();
     p.StartInfo.FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "myConsoleApp.exe";
     p.StartInfo.Arguments = name.Text;
     p.Start();
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` if you run this from Visual Studio returns the `bin` directory filepath, I would suggest that you place the .exe in the destination location of where your winforms app would run otherwise if it's a different location, then use the `App.Config` file to store the src location of  your Console App.

Answer (score 0):

Put it anywhere you want just specify the "WorkingDirectory".

```
Process p = new Process();
p.WorkingDirectory = "path";
```